# Steam crashes on startup

Tags: 14.04, drivers, games, steam

Steam used to work perfectly fine but today when I went to go run it, it would load up the "updating" bar then close and nothing would happen. I tried multiple times with no avail.

I tried running steam in the terminal and get

```
user@Alkarin-Desktop:~$ steam Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) Installing breakpad
exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar" Gtk-Message:
Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module" Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) Fontconfig error:
"/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element Fontconfig error:
"/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element Fontconfig warning:
"/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number [1103/145730:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(751)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak [1103/145730:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(189)]
Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on. 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20151014123328)     
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1444826008) 1103/145730:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(751)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak [1103/145730:ERROR:nss_util.cc(1007)] Failed to load NSS libraries.     
Illegal instruction (core dumped) Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1444853545)

Wireless receiver firmware
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/../controller_base/d0ggle.bin
loaded, version 1442256398. Installing breakpad exception handler for
appid(steam)/version(1444853545) Installing breakpad exception handler
for appid(steam)/version(1444853545) FillInMachineIDInfo took a total
of 0 milliseconds assert_20151103145729_1.dmp[4456]: Uploading dump
(out-of-process) /tmp/dumps/assert_20151103145729_1.dmp
assert_20151103145729_1.dmp[4456]: Finished uploading minidump
(out-of-process): success = no assert_20151103145729_1.dmp[4456]:
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory assert_20151103145729_1.dmp[4456]: file
''/tmp/dumps/assert_20151103145729_1.dmp'', upload no: ''libcurl.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory''
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 756:  4415 Illegal
instruction     (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER
"$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@" user@Alkarin-Desktop:~$
```

I've tried reinstalling my nvidia drivers and rebooting, uninstalling and reinstalling steam, and installing intel graphics drivers for linux. Still the same issue.
I've also now reinstalled curl and the steam launcher and still the same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this error

```
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

you might want to try installing curl then try running steam again

Comment: I already seemed to have curl installed. I uninstalled it with the steam launcher and reinstalled and its still the same issue.

Comment: is the libcurl error no more after that? What other messages left?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file : `/home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh`

```
sudo rm /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh
```

Then reinstall steam :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam
```