# Can't open steam on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, steam

I have tried to open steam on ubuntu 15.10 for hours but I just couldn't open.
I ran `steam` and the terminal just give me the following response:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0214/172141:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0214/172141:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(203)] Running without the SUID sandbox! 
/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454588499)
[0214/172141:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
assert_20160214172140_1.dmp[14581]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20160214172140_1.dmp
/home/loudavid/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 756: 14528 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
assert_20160214172140_1.dmp[14581]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20160214172140_1.dmp[14581]: response: CrashID=bp-09f1fea7-c2d5-4266-bece-3953c2160214
assert_20160214172140_1.dmp[14581]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20160214172140_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-09f1fea7-c2d5-4266-bece-3953c2160214''
```

Can anyone tell me what's my problem?

I have done what u say
but the terminal gave me the following response:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0214/174849:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0214/174849:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(203)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454588499)
[0214/174849:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
assert_20160214174848_1.dmp[2050]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20160214174848_1.dmp
/home/loudavid/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 756:  1996 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
assert_20160214174848_1.dmp[2050]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20160214174848_1.dmp[2050]: response: CrashID=bp-731419b9-6f11-4a29-acae-ee5f62160214
assert_20160214174848_1.dmp[2050]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20160214174848_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-731419b9-6f11-4a29-acae-ee5f62160214''
```

what's the problem now?

Again, i did what u told me, but still can't open, and gave me the following response:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0214/175555:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0214/175555:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(203)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454588499)
[0214/175555:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
assert_20160214175553_1.dmp[2351]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20160214175553_1.dmp
/home/loudavid/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 756:  2296 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
[0214/175556:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(622)] No browser info matching frame process id 2 and routing id 1
[0214/175556:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(622)] No browser info matching frame process id 2 and routing id 1
[0214/175556:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(622)] No browser info matching frame process id 2 and routing id 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
assert_20160214175553_1.dmp[2351]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20160214175553_1.dmp[2351]: response: CrashID=bp-f56594c9-5f62-49de-8d9a-5f1bb2160214
assert_20160214175553_1.dmp[2351]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20160214175553_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-f56594c9-5f62-49de-8d9a-5f1bb2160214''
```

Comment: Try : `sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386` on the terminal and restart ubuntu. And then run steam again.

Comment: I have already did what you told me
And i run steam

Comment: Try this on the terminal: `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam`. I think it works for you, in this case.

Comment: Comment did not fit the box, So I have forwarded it to the answer box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam crashes on startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/693647/steam-crashes-on-startup)

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file : /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh

`sudo rm /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh`

Then reinstall steam :

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam`

If this does not help, and you are using Nouveau driver, install proper Nvidia drivers by typing on the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`

Sources: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177245

[Steam crashes on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693647/steam-crashes-on-startup)

Comment: it shows this up:
sudo rm /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh